# Discretize all the columns in a dataframe pyton

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where all the columns are continous variables, and I want to discretize them in binnings based on frequency (so the binnings have the same size).

In order to do this I just apply the pd.cut function and iterate through the columns, however I'm getting the following errors:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df_q[column] = pd.qcut(df_q[column], 3)
<ipython-input-46-87e2efb9d039>:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df_q[column] = pd.qcut(df_q[column], 3)
<ipython-input-46-87e2efb9d039>:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

You can find a RepEx here:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load data
data = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

# Remove categorical variable and bin
df_q = df.loc[:, df.columns != "target"]
for column in df_q:
    df_q[column] = pd.qcut(df_q[column], 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not get any error or warning message when running your code. Do try to make a copy of `df` before creating `df_q`.

```
    df2 = df.copy()
    df_q = df2.loc[:, df2.columns != "target"]
```